# Proper understanding of Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

At the risk of asking a stupid question (and I will voluntarily delete the question myself if my peers think it is a stupid question)..

I have a C# desktop app.

I upload data to my server using a WCF Service.

I am experimenting with using Tasks.

This code calls my web service...

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => { wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes); });
```

I am stress testing this line of code.

I call it as many times in 1 second for a period of X time.

Will this 'flood' my router if the internet is slow for whatever reason?

I can sort of guess that this will be the case...

So, how can I test whether the task has completed before calling it again?  In doing this will the extra plumbing slow down my speed gains by using Task?

Finally, is using Tasks making usage of multiple cores?

Comment: A task has three final states: completed, canceled or failed. You can check the state using the properties on the task object.

Comment: Yes, using Task.Run will schedule the tasks to run on multiple cores. You should think of tasks as a more fine grained "piece of work" rather than a "thread". Basically, a task will be scheduled to run on a thread pool thread, but there is no exclusive mapping. Two tasks can be run in sequence on a given thread but it's up to the scheduler. You're not meant to think about it, other than abstractly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a simple explanation,  I told you this may have been a stupid question :).So, will the this tell me that the WCF call has completed as well?  (another stupid question - sorry)

Comment: Hi,  I was hoping that would be the case. Well worth moving away from Threads and background worker then

Comment: Can't tell you anything about wcf I'm afraid. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this 'flood' my router if the internet is slow for whatever
>   reason?

This depends on the size of the file you are uploading and you connection speed. To figure that out, just run .

> So, how can I test whether the task has completed before calling it
>   again?

You can use [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) function (any of available overloads) to "catch" task completion and run some other method, may be in recursion too.

> In doing this will the extra plumbing slow down my speed gains by
>   using Task?

It depends on workload, your processor and timing you expect. So, in other words, run it to measure, there is no possible generic answer to this.

> is using Tasks making usage of multiple cores?

Yes, whenever it figures out it is possible. Running single task one after another will not spread the single function work on multiple cores. For this you need to use [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) and similar artifacts.  And again, .NET does not provide you with a mechanism for SIMD orchestration, so you are not guaranteed that it *will* run on multicores, but most probably will.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a speedy answer. I will look at the Parallel and Continuewith now and report back.  The flooding router thing will just be down to the intermittent of the internet and network connections as the the byte array is always less than 2K.  So, my dilemma here is  that  I want to flush all the pending request calls to my server if things are building up?  Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: it depends if your server is able to handle the amount of requests you are going to query it...

Comment: Hi, well the approach I decided to take is to check IsCompleted on the client.  I will also put the Task mechanism in my server code - at the moment I use a simple lock which is not a great paradigm.  I will go by observation to see what happens and use DotMemeory to monitor resources.  I need to know the limits of my server and I will have to see how the data frequency upload and the magnitude affects resources. I am sure there is an equation I could use for all this (based on RAM and CPU). Perhaps another StackOverFlow Question...

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: sure,  you can find an equation, or pattern on your server, but it will valid only for *your* server's *current* hardware setup. Naturally it will vary between different runs, so you need to figure out acceptable tolerances.